# php scripts will not execute in browser

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, firefox, google-chrome

I'm trying to install wordpress...The install script will not run in firefox or chrome. I'm on ubuntu. I only get an option for downloading the file in both browsers. Any thoughts?

EDIT: Do I need to install libapache2-mod-php5?

Comment: Have you considered asking over at [Wordpress.se](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com)?

Answer (score 1):

That's a server setting in which the server is not set to process the .php file, but rather feed the file as a download... Inquire with your web host..

Comment: Um. I'm guessing you are using some sort of an apache emulator such as LAMP or MAMP?

Answer (score 0):

you need to install apache and PHP running before trying to run any PHP script. download this. http://www.sph.umich.edu/csg/abecasis/LAMP/download/

Comment: I have apache and php installed

Comment: did you set your connection string properly. be precise about your problem. you are only confusing us.

Comment: What is the connection string?

Comment: wordpress uses the database like mySQL, you need to establish a connection with your server to make the wordpress running. here is the settings you need to make. http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php

Answer (score 0):

Try out this one,

http://www.supriyadisw.net/2006/12/wordpress-installation-on-ubuntu-with-lamp

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you need the server, but you've said you already have the server installed. Did you access the PHP file via the server, or via the file path?
Server would be http://127.0.0.1 (or localhost, or your IP)

If so, you may not have set PHP up correctly with Apache.

The easiest way to set it up is to install [Lampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html), it is my favourite, and is really easy to install and remove. Once installed, just copy the Wordpress files into the /opt/lampp/htdocs directory, and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install libapache2-mod-php5, make sure the module was loaded in apache, then restart apache. All seemed to work fine in firefox afterwards, but not in chrome. I also had to move the wordpress install to /var/www

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day, and in any case, if your *.php files are downloading rather than being *run*, it means that there is no handler on your host for interpreting/processing these the correct way.

If one browser reports a problem, and the other doesn't - something is terribly wrong and could be something to do with caching, and is usually indicative of running a local web server on the same machine.

Apache is the webserver and it could be configured to *see* your website at /var/www - but you still need PHP and its applicable apache-related libraries installed for PHP pages to be delivered by the webserver the correct way.

If you are using a Windows computer, I would ditch it and buy a Mac.